# C: sem_open oflags

Tags: c, header-files, semaphore

I'm trying to learn how to use semaphores and I'm kinda confused about their general usage. I'm trying to understand an example I was given.

Here's the initialization of a semaphore in the first process:

```
sem_t *s1 = sem_open(SEM_1, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 1);
```

Where SEM_1 is a predefined name.

My issue starts with the `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` part. I understand that you're setting an O_ flag when you create a semaphore. `O_CREAT` is supposed to create a semaphore. `O_EXCL` should make the call fail if it's already created. What I'm not sure about is how it's specified here. The man pages for sem_open say:

"If  both O_CREAT and O_EXCL are specified in oflag,
       then an error is returned if a semaphore with the  given  name  already
       exists."

If I understand correctly, `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` is just specifying both (bit-wise OR linking), correct? What's the purpose of just O_EXCL, then?

Continuing on, I understand that 0600 are the permissions and 1 is the semaphore value. Then there's the semaphore in the next process:

```
sem_t *s1 = sem_open(SEM_1, 0);
```

Looking up the definition for 0 in fcntl.h reveals

```
#define O_RDONLY    00000000
```

Which I assume is used here. Wouldn't that kinda defeat a semaphore's purpose, though, since I'd need to increment/decrement it's value eventually?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

> If I understand correctly, `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` is just
>   specifying both (bit-wise OR linking), correct?

Correct.

> What's the purpose of just O_EXCL, then?

Specifying *just* `O_EXCL`, i. e. calling `sem_open(SEM_1, O_EXCL)`, is not defined and not meaningful.

> Then there's the semaphore in the next process:
>
> ```
> sem_t *s1 = sem_open(SEM_1, 0);
> ```
>
> Looking up the definition for 0 in fcntl.h reveals
>
> ```
> #define O_RDONLY    00000000
> ```
>
> Which I assume is used here.

You shouldn't make unfounded assumptions. The meaning of the `oflag` argument is defined in the manual of `sem_open`, and that completely. There are no other flags beside `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` - that `0` just means that none of those flags is given.